# Psycopg2 неправильно выполняет SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = {data}

Tags: python, база-данных, postgresql, telebot, psycopg2

Пишу Telegram-бота на Python с использованием PostgreSQL для хранения данных. Имеется две функции для получения пользователя из базы: 1 - по его user_id; 2 - по его username.
Первая функция ( по user_id ) работает прекрасно, без ошибок, вторая же делает, что-то не так.

Первая функция ( по user_id ):

```
def db_get_user_userid(user_id):
    cursor.execute(f'SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = {user_id}')
    user = cursor.fetchone()

    user_id = user[1]
    username = user[2]
    admin = user[3]
    add_date = user[4]

    return user_id, username, admin, add_date
```

Вторая функция ( по username ):

```
def db_get_user_username(username):
    cursor.execute(f'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = {username}')
    user = cursor.fetchone()

    user_id = user[1]
    username = user[2]
    admin = user[3]
    add_date = user[4]

    return user_id, username, admin, add_date
```

Проблема со второй функцией заключается в том, что psycopg2 почему-то считает подставляемый username названием колонки, когда в первой функции с user_id всё работает нормально.

Вывод в консоли:

```
column "beirym" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = Beirym
```

Также пробовал менять SQL-запрос на вот такой:

```
def db_get_user_username(username):
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = %s', (username, ))
    user = cursor.fetchone()

    user_id = user[1]
    username = user[2]
    admin = user[3]
    add_date = user[4]

    return user_id, username, admin, add_date
```

Но и это не помогло, psycopg2 всё-равно считает передаваемый {username} названием колонки в таблице.

Несколько часов искал информацию в гугле, но так ничего и не нашёл.
Надеюсь на помощь, спасибо!

Comment: psycopg2 считает `Beirym` названием колонки потому, что вы передаете строковое значение без кавычек. Не знаю, почему у Вас не сработал вариант с аргументом в execute, но все же предлагаю еще раз попробовать вот так `cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = %s;', [username])`

Comment: Хотя может я и не прав, но скорее всего советы из того вопроса, к которому я обозначил этот как дубликат, должны помочь. Если не помогут - напишите тут, переоткроем вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спустя много часов гуглёшки, нашёл решение своей проблемы.

Помогла функция `AsIs()` из модуля `psycopg2.extensions`.

Код теперь выглядит так:

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extensions import AsIs

def db_get_user_username(username):

    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE %s = %s', (AsIs('username'), username))
    user = cursor.fetchone()

    user_id = user[1]
    username = user[2]
    admin = user[3]
    add_date = user[4]

    return user_id, username, admin, add_date
```

Answer (score -1):

Здравствуй!
Не уверен, что лучшее решение, но лично я просто делаю кавычки перед и после строковой переменной в запросе. В вашем случае, это примерно так:

```
cursor.execute(f'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = "{username}" ')
```

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло. Ошибка всё таже:

column "Beirym" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = "Beirym"

Comment: Не учите плохому. Использование `f` строк для передачи аргументов в запрос, очень нехорошая практика

Comment: @Namerek хм, можете немного подробнее рассказать, почему не стоит так делать? (И да, имеете в виду в целом форматирование строк в sql запрос или конкретно f-строковое форматирование?)  Просто сам не так давно на asyncpg подобный функционал через f-строки делал, чем-то может быть опасно?

Comment: @Sasonit, справедливости ради в данном конкретном случае пофиг вааще, если код не получает параметры для запроса извне, за исключением нюанса, когда значение, которое вы предполагали, будет строковым, вдруг оказывается None. А что касается безопасности, то в случае если программа получает значения параметров запроса извне, то возможно получить инъекцию. По этим и други причинам практика использования `f` строк для форматирования SQL запросов считается не самой лучшей практикой.

Comment: ИМХО  проще сразу научиться использовать инструментарий библиотеки для работы аргументами запросов, чем потом переучиваться и переделывать